# HTML input type file open sevrer files

Tags: javascript, html

A file server is running at http://localhost:8082 and now with `<input type="file" />` I have to display those server files when we click on this input.

Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `<input type="file" />` displays local files for uploading.

If you want to display files from an HTTP server you'll need to write your own UI (possibly writing a web service that will provide the list and accessing it with Ajax).